# Where woocommerce file send emails

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

When I send an email, I need to send a part of this data using the POST request to send an JSON array. Where is the executable file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WordPress/WooCommerce uses hooks if you want to modify any behaviour, in your case lets say you want to capture the data that is being sent in the email. you can use the following hooks for that.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_low_stock_notification', array( $object, 'low_stock' ) );
add_action( 'woocommerce_no_stock_notification', array( $object, 'no_stock' ) );
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_on_backorder_notification', array( $object, 'backorder' ) );
add_action( 'woocommerce_created_customer_notification', array( $object, 'customer_new_account' ), 10, 3 );
```

Learn more about hooks in here: https://blog.teamtreehouse.com/hooks-wordpress-actions-filters-examples

PS: you must avoid modifying the core files.